# Use correct email address in reportbug

Tags: bug-reporting

I am using `reportbug` to report a bug. However, it uses `My Name <username@name-of-computer>` as the from address instead of `My Name <email@address>`. How to use my email address in `reportbug`?

Note: I am trying to submit a new package to Debian (so that it will be later included in Ubuntu). The standard procedure is to use reportbug to submit a bug report against the pseudo-package WNPP, and this bug will be used as a reference until the package is accecpted. This is why I have to use `reportbug` and not `ubuntu-bug`. Also, note that I am not asking questions about how to submit bug report to Debian. I am asking a specific question about how to configure reportbug, which is in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: As far as I know you file a bug on -launchpad- against the Ubuntu package and it is then sent upstream

Comment: Check this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages. When the software is approved in Debian repositories, that bug will be closed. There is no other way to submit a new package to Debian. I understand that Ask Ubuntu is not the place to ask question about reporting bugs about Debian. But this is a special case where one needs to report bug to Debian so that the package will be eventually accepted in Ubuntu.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Very good!  +1  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reportbug --configure` and it will ask about your name, email address, and other details.

Comment: why `-B debian`? (I am well aware how I can find this information, but your answer would be a lot better if it explained this)

Comment: @vidarlo I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [`man reportbug`, section Environment](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/reportbug.1.html#environment):

```
REPORTBUGEMAIL, DEBEMAIL, EMAIL
  Email address to use as your from  address  (in  this  order).  If  no  
  environment variable exists, the default is taken from your user name
  and /etc/mailname.
```

So, you can also set one of these environment variables instead (or edit `/etc/mailname`, which probably only makes sense if you're running a mail server).